# Performance issues with ADO.Net Datasets

Tags: crystal-reports

I really want to know your experience at working with ADO.Net datasets (calling stored procedures from SQL) and Crystal Reports, I know about the 2-4 seconds to

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument document = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
document.Load(file);
```

but what about the load of each tableadapter is there another way to work with Crystal Reports? Maybe with LINQ

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used DataSets with Crystal.  In general I do not like to allow Crystal Reports to fetch its own data as we have had errors with it opening too many connections to the Database.  I usually create a DataSet and serialize it to XML with the schema and use the xml file as the ADO.Net "DataBase" for design purposes and then at runtime I assign the DataSet to the Report

```
Dim rd As New ReportDocument
        rd.Load("SomeReport.rpt")
        rd.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(dataset)
```

Comment: thats the way Im working right now, BTW It stills being so slow and lacking RAM